# Caching remote files with python

Tags: python, caching

**Background**

We have a lot of data files stored on a network drive which we process in python. For performance reasons I typically copy the files to my local SSD when processing. My wish is to make this happen automatically, so whenever I try to open a file it will grab the remote version if it isn't stored locally, and ideally also keep some sort of timer to delete the files after some time. The files will practically never be changed so I do not require actual syncing capabilities.

**Functionality**

To sum up what I am looking for is functionality for:

- Keeping a local cache of files/directories from a network drive, automatically retrieving the remote version when unavailable locally
- Support for directory structure - that is, the files are stored in a directory structure on the remote server which should be duplicated locally for the requested files
- Ideally keep some sort of timer to expire cached files

It wouldn't be to difficult for me to write a piece of code which does this my self, but when possible, I prefer to rely on existing projects as this typically give a more versatile end result and also make any of my own improvements easily available to other users.

**Question**

I have searched a bit around for terms like python local file cache, file synchronization and the like, but what I have found mostly handles caching of function return values. I was a bit surprised because I would imagine this is a quite general problem, my question is therefore: is there something I have overlooked, and more importantly, are there any technical terms describing this functionality which could help my research.

Thank you in advance,
Gregers Poulsen

***-- Update --***

Due to other proprietary software packages I am forced to use Windows so the solution naturally must support this.

Comment: You may want to have a look at [pcachefs](https://code.google.com/p/pcachefs/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I am however forced to work on Windows due to other proprietary software packages, so that is really not an option for me :(

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at fsspec remote caching, with [a tutorial on the anaconda blog](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/fsspec-remote-caching) and [the official documentation](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features.html#caching-files-locally).  Quoting the former:

> In this article, we will present [fsspec]s new ability to cache remote content, keeping a local copy for faster lookup after the initial read.

They give an example for how to use it:

> ```py
> import fsspec
> of = fsspec.open("filecache://anaconda-public-datasets/iris/iris.csv", mode='rt', 
>                  cache_storage='/tmp/cache1',
>                  target_protocol='s3', target_options={'anon': True})
> with of as f:
>     print(f.readline())
> ```

On first call, the file will be downloaded, stored into cache, and provided.  On the second call, it will be downloaded from the local filesystem.

I haven't used it yet, but I need it and it looks promising.